# How do you clear/flush kube-dns cache in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

How do you clear the Kube-dns cache in Google Kubernetes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike kube-dns cloud dns won’t maintain any servers instead it caches data locally in each node. Compute engine metadata server performs this function and we can’t send any manual interrupts for clearing the cache from metadata servers.

So, if you have configured a load balancer for exposing your gke environment to outer world you can perform [cache invalidation](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/invalidating-cached-content) and if you didn’t configured any LB you can disable cloud dns and enable it again for maintaining the dns records first create a kube-dns deployment transfer the configs from cloud dns to kube-dns and now disable and re-enable cloud dns for gke.